# Entity Framework Core: Update() method INSERTs instead of UPDATEs on dependent entity

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

It seems like EF Core is doing an INSERT instead of an UPDATE, and thus MySQL complains about a duplicate key. However, I am using the Update method on the DbSet and the entities do have primary keys set. This results in a DUPLICATE ENTRY error in MySql.

*Running VS 2019, EF Core 3.1.1 and ASP.NET Core 3.1*

**Model (I do not use Fluent config for relationships, just Convention):**

```
public class Vehicle 
{
    public long Id {get; set; } // PRIMARY KEY, AUTO INCREMENT
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }
    public VehicleSession Session { get; set; }
}


public class VehicleSession
{
    public long VehicleId { get; set; }
    public Vehicle Vehicle { get; set; }
    public string DeviceUuid { get; set; } // PRIMARY KEY
    public string AuthenticationToken { get; set; }
    public string OSName { get; set; }
    public string OSVersion { get; set; }
    public string DeviceModel { get; set; }
}
```

**Database:**

Table 'vehiclesessions' where the PRIMARY KEY is DeviceUuid and has key 'device2':

[image]

**Controller:**

A request comes in from somewhere. DeviceUuid is fetched from HTTP headers.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<VehicleLoginResponse>> Login(VehicleLogin login)
    {
        Request.Headers.TryGetValue(BaseConstants.DEVICE_UUID, out StringValues deviceUuid);
        Vehicle vehicle = await vehicleService.Authenticate(login.Username, login.Password); // returns a Vehicle by asking dbContet: dbContext.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Username.Equals(username));
        VehicleSession vs = await vehicleService.CreateSession(vehicle, login, deviceUuid);
        // ...
    }
```

**Service:**

This service creates a new VehicleSession object, assigns it to the Vehicle property, and does an .Update on the Vehicle, so that the new session is saved with it.

```
    public async Task<VehicleSession> CreateSession(Vehicle vehicle, VehicleLogin vehicleLogin, string deviceUuid)
    {
        VehicleSession vs = new VehicleSession()
        {
            Vehicle = vehicle,
            AuthenticationToken = someTokenFetchedFromSomewhere,
            DeviceModel = vehicleLogin.DeviceModel,
            DeviceUuid = deviceUuid, // is 'device2'
            OSName = vehicleLogin.OSName,
            OSVersion = vehicleLogin.OSVersion
        };

        vehicle.Session = vs;
        dbContext.Vehicles.Update(vehicle);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return vs;
    }
```

It doesn't matter if I replace the `new VehicleSession` and assignment, with just editing an already existing Vehicle.Session, same error:

```
    public async Task<VehicleSession> CreateSession(Vehicle vehicle, VehicleLogin vehicleLogin, string deviceUuid)
    {
        if (vehicle.Session == null)
            vehicle.Session = new VehicleSession(); // never executes this line
        vehicle.Session.AuthenticationToken = someTokenFetchedFromSomewhere;

        vehicle.Session.DeviceModel = vehicleLogin.DeviceModel;
        vehicle.Session.DeviceUuid = deviceUuid;
        vehicle.Session.OSName = vehicleLogin.OSName;
        vehicle.Session.OSVersion = vehicleLogin.OSVersion;

        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return vehicle.Session;
    }
```

When doing so, I get an error saying:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.  --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry
>   'device2' for key 'vehiclesessions.PRIMARY'  --->
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry
>   'device2' for key 'vehiclesessions.PRIMARY'

The SQL produced:

```
 Failed executing DbCommand (125ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 95), @p1='?' (Size = 95), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (Size = 4000), @p4='?' (Size = 4000), @p5='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO `VehicleSessions` (`DeviceUuid`, `AuthenticationToken`, `DeviceModel`, `OSName`, `OSVersion`, `VehicleId`)
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5);
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'blabla'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry 'device2' for key 'vehiclesessions.PRIMARY'
       ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Duplicate entry 'device2' for key 'vehiclesessions.PRIMARY'
```

Why am I getting this error? It seems like an INSERT is done instead of an UPDATE, even though the Vehicle object is fetched from dbContext, passed along and has PRIMARY id set.

Comment: I am missing the part wher you generate or uuid, something like Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid(); because your seem not ti generate or else mysql wouldn't mind

Comment: Guid doesn't matter, it's just a string. That is not the issue.

Comment: The DeviceUUID comes from elsewhere, it is not generated in the service. But again, it is not the issue. The issue is why it seems there is an INSERT made in the vehiclesession, instead of an UPDATE as I would expect.

Comment: That is a misconception Vehicles.Update(vehicle) tries to send all changes to the database, and programmed vehicle.Session = vs and vs is a new element, so it tries to send it to the database. new elment equals INSERT

Comment: Thanks, but I tried to not do a 'new...', but instead just updating some values inside the existing VehicleSessions object. Same error. This is noted above in the question.
I just tried it again, "duplicate" error, same as before.

Comment: What EF Core version are you using? Also, the intended relationship is one-to-one, correct? Can you post the fluent configuration of the entities in question and their relationship.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019, EF Core 3.1.1, ASP.NET Core 3.1. I dont use Fluent config, just Convention on this case, so the classes at the top of the posts should show all. yes, its a one-to-one relationship, one Vehicle has one VehicleSession.

Comment: Hmm, then `DeviceUuid` is not PK for EF Core. With just classes  I'm getting error "The entity type 'VehicleSession' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'."

Comment: Ah, sorry, sorry. I thought u meant relationships. I do have some stuff like that, so keys are set correctly: `builder.HasIndex(p => new { p.DeviceUuid, p.AuthenticationToken });`  and `builder.HasKey(p => p.DeviceUuid);`. The problem isnt creating the keys, indexes etc, they are all there as expected. The problem is that it is trying to INSERT instead of UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think I might have found the issue.

As noted above, I first did a search to retrieve the Vehicle, like this:

`Vehicle vehicle = dbContext.Vehicles.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Username.Equals(username));`

In this case, the Vehicle.Session, if one existed, was *not* populated. Later on, I did the update as the code above shows, and it failed as noted above.

But, if I change the fetch code to this:

```
Vehicle entityVehicle = dbContext.Vehicles
    .Include(x => x.Session)// <-- NEW!
    .FirstOrDefault(v => v.Username.Equals(username));
```

then it works.

It doesn't matter if I assign the .Session a `new VehicleSession(...)` or if I change the properties in the existing object. It also doesn't matter if I use `dbContext.Vehicles.Update(vehicle);` before `await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();`, the call to `.Update(...)` is not needed.

The only thing that made a difference, was to use `.Include(...)`.

---

My own theory is:

When fetching the object from db, the EF Core "tracker" starts tracking. Property `Session` is NULL. When `Session` later is populated, the tracker detects that it *was* NULL but now is *not* NULL, thus, it figures that an INSERT is needed.

And then, if you populate the `Session` on fetch, tracker sees it is there, and should be updated.

Comment: Just stumbled across this issue in v2.2. While your explanation makes sense, this seems like it should be a bug. Even if it was null, in my case, relationship fix-up is setting that property automatically. Why should I have to handle something like this when EF Core is doing this without my asking?